# PHP scramble txt file while keeping some parts the same

Tags: php

consider a  txt file like this

```
@[111:a]@[222:a]@[333:a]
@[444:a]@[555:a]@[666:a]
@[777:a]@[888:a]@[999:a]
```

and I want to scramble it in such a way that the values between @[ and :a] are reordered randomly like the example below:

```
@[777:a]@[555:a]@[999:a]
@[444:a]@[222:a]@[888:a]
@[111:a]@[666:a]@[333:a]
```

Comment: Is the syntax always `\@\[[0-9]+\:a\]` for each unit? And do you want it written back to the same file? Or what do you want to do with it? Is it always 3x3?

Comment: the output could be a new txt file or the same file. the matrix is n*10. I don't think the dimension should matter

Comment: I really want to know what uses this format.

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = <<<EOF
@[111:a]@[222:a]@[333:a]
@[444:a]@[555:a]@[666:a]
@[777:a]@[888:a]@[999:a]
EOF;

preg_match_all('/@\[[^\]]+\]/', $file, $matches);
shuffle($matches[0]);
echo join(PHP_EOL, array_map('join', array_chunk($matches[0], 3)));
```

It's essentially just parsing all items into an array, shuffling the array, then outputting them again three per line.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$content = '';
preg_match_all("/@\[[0-9]+\:a\]/", file_get_contents("file.txt"), $matches);
$matches = $matches[0];

shuffle($matches); //shuffle array's order

foreach($matches as $match) {
     $content .= $match;
}

file_put_contents("file.txt", $content);
?>
```

Note that you might get permissions errors.

Comment: That regex looks really familiar. . . :)

Comment: Yeap ! I see your comment :) Sorry, can  i use it? I can rewrite it? haha

Comment: Ha-ha, no problem, but your code as-is doesn't work.  I tested it out.

Comment: Well, I switched it to use preg_match_all instead of preg_match, which is why it needed the removal of the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the whole thing on `]` with `explode()`, though you need to append the `]` back onto each element. Shuffle the array then output it again.

```
$string = file_get_contents('file.txt');

// Split into an array on the right bracket, and strip out line breaks.
$array = explode("]", str_replace("\n", "", $string));

// Shuffle it
shuffle($array);

$output = "";

// Iterate over the array assembling it back into a string
$len = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
  // Don't forget to add the right bracket back on
  $output .= $array[$i] . "]";
  // Linebreak every 3rd element.
  if ($i % 3 == 0) $output .= "\n";
}

// Write out to file
file_put_contents("output.txt", $output);
```

Comment: @LeviMorrison missing a `(`. Fixed .

Answer (score 0):

What about breaking it up and randomizing the order?

```
$contents = file_get_contents('thefile.txt'); //read file contents
$parts = explode('@', $contents); //split it into an array by its @ character
shuffle($parts); //shuffle the array
$result = ""; //create a base string
$i = 0; //counter
foreach($parts as $part)
{
   $part = trim($part); //Remove any spaces before or after string part.
   $result .= '@'.$part; //add it to the result with the @ again.
   $i++;
   if($i % 3 >= 3) //If we are over a 3rd one we insert a new line
         $result .="\r\n";
}
file_put_contents('destination.txt', $result); //Save the file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = '@[111:a]@[222:a]@[333:a]
@[444:a]@[555:a]@[666:a]
@[777:a]@[888:a]@[999:a]';

// parse input
preg_match_all('/@\[[0-9]+:a]/', $input, $matches);
$matches = $matches[0];

// randomise
shuffle($matches);

// create output
$output = '';
$columns = 0;
foreach ($matches as $match) {
  $output .= $match;

  $columns++;
  if ($columns == 3) {
    $output .= "\n";
    $columns = 0;
  }
}

// print output as html
print nl2br($output);
```